# Proxy APN Configuration

Tags: android, proxy, apn

I want to set by code the proxy configuration (Address and port) in the 3G APN for Android.

Is that possible ?
If it's yes how i can do that?

I found some solution by googling, but it's seems not working for the ICS(Android >=4.0).

Thank you in advance.